# Default home page of MVC application is always redirecting to logon screen (IIS7)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008, authorization

I'm having a bit of an issue setting up our test site.

In IIS 7, our app pool for the site is running in integrated mode.

In Authentication, I have Anon enabled and Forms auth enabled.

In Authorization, I have Allow All users.

All pages allow anon users, EXCEPT the default (Home/Index.aspx).  That page always forwards the user to the login screen.  I want them to see the homepage.

I have tried adding authorization rules to the webconfig, but nothing changes it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the NTFS security settings in IIS 7.  I added the anon user accounts to have access and the site works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you haven't set the Authorize (C#) attribute on either the Home controller or the Index action.

Comment: I do not have that C# attribute attached to either my controller or the Index action.